# How to automatically set a field based on another field when inserting a row in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Using PostgreSQL, I need to automatically set a field value in an inserted row based on the output of a function using another field from the very same row that is being inserted. For example, given a table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
    id           UUID                     DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    code         VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    value        VARCHAR(50),
    last_updated TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT now()
)
```

When inserting a new row e.g.

```
INSERT INTO my_table (code, value)
VALUES ('a','a'), 
       ('b','b');
```

I need the field `my_table.id` to be automatically set for those two new rows based on the output of this parametrized function based on `value`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION gen_deterministic_id(val varchar)
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
    NEW.id = md5('xx' ||  val)::uuid;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

**NOTE**: I really need the function to be parametrizable (to be able to pass any parameter).

The pseudocode would be something like this:

```
for each new row:
    row.id = gen_deterministic_id(row.value)
    then insert_to_table
```

Do you guys know if this is possible to implement using e.g. triggers or the like in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TRIGGER` returning functions don't accept any parameters. But you can use the values directly in the function with `NEW.value`

**Option 1:** You can create a trigger:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3b647f63f6bf9b4a5b838e9735e36a54)

```
CREATE FUNCTION gen_deterministic_id()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN
    NEW.id = md5('xx' || NEW.value)::uuid;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER generate_uuid
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON my_table
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE gen_deterministic_id();
```

**Option 2:** You can use the new **Postgres 12** feature: [Generated Columns](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=43f49bc9cb8a898aec5251cbe7709182)

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
    id           uuid GENERATED ALWAYS AS (md5('xx' ||  value)::uuid) STORED, -- 1
    code         VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    value        VARCHAR(50),
    last_updated TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT now()
);
```

1. This column keeps calculated results based on the inserted record.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed! The new Postgres 12 feature is fantastic, and it would serve my purpose even better if it wasn't for the fact that Azure Postgres Server doesn't support that version yet (only up to Postgres 11 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/concepts-supported-versions). Anyway, this answers my question. Thanks a lot :-)